# ¿Cómo puedo seleccionar una hoja de estilo dependiendo de la base de datos?

Tags: javascript, c#, css

Lo que quiero conseguir es que dependiendo de las plantas que tenga mi empresa, me seleccione un `.css` diferente con estilos personalizados. Si tengo de 0 a 3 me jale una hoja específica, si tengo de 4 a 6 me jale otra diferente etc.

Esto lo quiero hacer porque actualmente estoy trabajando con una accordeón y dicho accordeón no es del todo dinámico ya que funciona corrrectamente pero si aumentan o disminuyen  las plantas el accordeón no ocupa todo el espacio que debería.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que se pueda apreciar el espacio que queda libre, ese espacio aumentará conforme menos plantas haya, lo cual está erroneo ya que quiero que se aproveche todo el espacio por lo cual quisiera hacer 3 `.css` personalizados para tres diferentes posibilidades de la base de datos y seleccionarlos cuando se pueda.

1. Primer .css (0-3 plantas)
2. Segundo .css (4-8 plantas)
3. Tercer .css(9-12 plantas)

El espacio que quiero aprovechar es el que se realiza al momento de abririse.

Código de `css` para abrir cada accordeón:

```
 .ia-container input:checked ~ figure {
        -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.7s ease-in-out;
        left: 65%;
    }
```

Como se puede apreciar el `left:65%`, es el que genera que se abra ciertas dimensiones cada accordeón y es estático, quiero generarlo dinámicamente.

Comment: Hola David, ¿todo lo requieres hacer directamente en del lado del cliente? es decir, ¿solo modificando las hojas de estilos es como deseas implementar esta funcionalidad?

Comment: @david la libreria sass te podria ayudar

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo funcional de tu problema para poder reproducirlo?

Comment: @guzgarcia por el momento no tengo ningún ejemplo re producible.

Comment: @flxtr si todo eso sera del lado del cliente claro que traeré información de la BD para combinarlo con la parte del cliente y poder generar una manera de intercalar los .css

Comment: que es una planta?, como renderizas una planta? de qué depende la cantidad de plantas?. No hay necesidad de tener 3 archivos css diferentes

Comment: @Mauro Aguilar Bustamante una planta es una sucursal de la empresa en diferente ubicación geográfica, la cantidad de plantas depende de la información de la BD, esta información la ingresa el cliente o la empresa. me gustaria saber la forma de hacerlo sin la necesidad de 3 .css diferentes

Comment: @David ¿nos podrías indicar qué tecnologías utilizas del lado del server? ¿MVC, WebForms ...?

Comment: No necesitar tener diferentes .css, solo necesitas crear clases para cada configuración según tu necesidad, un solo archivo .css con los diferentes estilos, con jquery puedes dependiendo de las "plantas" asignar los estilos correspondientes a tus controles.  O mas fácilmente ponerle estilos fijos, como una regla de que estilo le corresponde a tal numero de planta.... te complicas mucho pensando en hacer 3 archivos... es programación WEB... ya no es de escritorio....

Comment: @Flxtr de el lado del servidor utilizo C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para evitar generar 3 archivos css diferentes puedes declarar los estilos que necesites en diferentes clases css dentro de un solo archivo.

```
.style1 .container {
  background: #FFF;
}

.style2 .container {
  background: #FAFAFA;
}
```

Usa algun preprocesador de css como [sass](http://sass-lang.com/) o [less](http://lesscss.org/) para agilizar las cosas.

En cuanto al cambio de estilos, si el html que renderizas es dinámico, bastaría con cambiar el nombre de la clase del elemento contenedor desde javascript.

Un ejemplo sencillo con jquery y los estilos anteriores podría ser:

```
$('.main').removeClass('style1').addClass('style2');
```

Si el renderizado del contenido depende completamente del servidor, implementa la lógica para seleccionar una clase css u otra en función de lo que tengas en tu base de datos, un par condicionales o un switch-case debería bastar, agregala a tu html antes de enviar la página al cliente.

Por último y como recomendación creo que deberías buscar la forma de estructurar tu aplicación con un diseño general que se adapte a la mayoría de las condiciones, requerimientos o reglas de negocio de la misma. El hecho de realizar estilos específicos indica que algo no esta bien y que se puede mejorar. Puede llegar a ser bastante tedioso cambiar algo en un futuro si los requerimientos cambian y el diseño inicial ya no se adapta a las nuevas necesidades.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo se trata de un desarrollo en asp.net usando c#, entonces podrias aplicar diferentes estilos segun los datos que dispongas en cada momento

Hay varias formas de lograrlo, sino quieres 3 css diferentes quizas este dato dinamico podrias quitarlo de la hoja de estilo y definirlo como style donde coresponda

Si obtienes el dato de la db podrias asignar este en una propiedad de la pagina para luego ser usado en el aspx

```
public class Page1
{
    public string Left {get;set;}

    public void Page_Load(...)
    {
        //aqui consultas la tabla
        ths.Left = "65"; //aqui asignas el valor que recuperas de la db
    }

    //resto codigo pagina

}
```

y en el aspx seria

```
<div class="ia-container" style="left:<%=this.Left%>%;">
```

como veras se usa el <%= %> para renderiza en ese sitio el valor que previamente recuperaste de la db

Comment: Esto suponiendo que el OP utiliza WebForms. Me parece que es una pregunta muy amplia, a lo mejor sería de más ayuda que ponga en concreto las tecnologías que utiliza y ya con eso podríamos dar con una respuesta